# Split up a number as the sum of two powers

Tags: python, algorithm, math, optimization

x is my input. 
I need to find i,j>=0 and  n,m>1 such as `x = i**m+j**n`

For now I have been doing this , but it is way to slow !! How can I improve it ?

```
from math import sqrt
import numpy as np

def check(x):
    for i in range(1,int(np.ceil(sqrt(x)))):
        for j in range(1,int(np.ceil(sqrt(x)))):
            for m in range(2,x/2+1):
                for n in range(2,x/2+1):
                    if((pow(i,m) +pow(j,n))==x):
                        print 'Yes';
                        return ;
    print 'No';
```

thank you !

Comment: this might not be the best place to ask this question but one thing you can do is make sure you exit a loop if the values would always surpass x: if x is 10 and you have `i = 3`  then checking anything when `m > 3` is pointless since it will always be bigger than 10, i could elaborate more about this but tell me if that's the direction you want

Comment: What is the purpose of doing `int(np.ceil(x))` if x is a single number? Also storing the result of `x/2+1` and using it in the m and n iterations might be faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reverse the process, by finding all powers (i**m) smaller than x. Then you just check if any pair of these powers adds up to x.

```
def check(x):
    all_powers = set([1]) #add 1 as a special case

    #find all powers smaller than x 
    for base in range(2,int(math.ceil(sqrt(x)))):
        exponent = 2;
        while pow(base, exponent) < x:
            all_powers.add(pow(base, exponent))
            exponent+=1

    #check if a pair of elements in all_powers adds up to x
    for power in all_powers:
        if (x - power) in all_powers:
            print 'Yes'
            return
    print 'No'
```

The code above is simple but can be optimized, e.g., by integrating the check if a pair adds up to x in the while loop you can stop early in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

From time to time a question pops up here about determining if a positive integer is the integral power of another positive integer. I.e. given positive integer `z` find positive integers `j` and `n` such that `z == j**n`. This can be done in time complexity `O(log(z))` so it is fairly fast.

So find or develop such a routine: call it `is_a_power(z)` which returns a tuple `(j, n)` if `z` is such a power of `(0, 0)` if it is not. Then loop over `i` and `m`, then check if `x - i**m` is a power. When it becomes one, you are done.

I'll let you finish the code from here, except for one more pointer. Given `x` and `i` where `i > 1`, you can find the upper limit on `m` such that `i**m <= x` with

```
m <= log(x) / log(i)
```

Note that `i == 1` is a special case, since `i**m` does not actually depend on `m` in that case.

Answer (score 0):

```
from math import sqrt
import numpy as np
def build(x):
# this function creates number that are in form of
# a^b such that a^b <= x and b>1
  sq=sqrt(x);
  dict[1]:1; # 1 is always obtainable
  dict[0]:1; # also 0 is always obtainable
  for i in range(1,sq): # try the base
    number=i*i; # firstly our number is i^2
    while number<=x: 
      dict[number]:1; # this number is in form of a^b
      number*=i; # increase power of the number
def check(x):
  sq=sqrt(x);
  for i in range(1,sq): # we will try base of the first number
    firstnumber=1;
    while firstnumber<=x: # we are trying powers of i
      remaining=x-firstnumber; # this number is remaining number when we substract firstnumber from x
      if dict[remaining]==1: # if remaining number is in dictionary which means it is representable as a^b
        print("YES");  # then print YES
        return ;
      firstnumber*=i; # increase the power of the base
  print("NO");
  return ;
```

Above code works in O( sqrt(x) * log(x) * log(x) ) which is faster.

You can read comments in code to understand it.